# What is the easiest way to make lowercase chars uppercase, and vice versa?

Tags: java

I am doing a decoder program. The instructions printed by the teacher say this:

> Lowercase characters become uppercase characters.
>
> Uppercase characters become lowercase characters.
>
> Digits 0-9 become A-J
>
> Any other characters become #

Which method will be the easiest and least burdening to type up and read afterwards? I was thinking of using if commands, but having:

```
if(let=a||let=b||let=c); //and so on and so forth, rinse and repeat for uppercase letters.
```

will be really unreadable, and will just kill my typing hands.

Comment: Are you meant that you want to write code yourself instead of using the API which jdk has provided?

Comment: The Java library has methods in the `java.lang.Character` class to determine if a character is uppercase, lowercase, or a digit. That will make your life much easier. It also has methods to convert to uppercase and to lowercase. For the conversion of digits to letters you can rely on the fact that the numeric value of digits and letters are in the same order.

Comment: @saka1029 Yes, and? For both examples, that is correct. I guess for the digits that may be a bit difficult so perhaps better to check `ch >= '0' && ch <= '9'` but for the letters it won't cause a problem because the methods in character to convert to lower and uppercase will handle that right.

Answer (score 2):

Since this is an assignment, I'm just going to give you a hint (by no means the only way to do it, just one way). You're right that there is a more programmatic way to do it, and that's likely going to involve taking advantage of the fact that `chars` are easily converted to numbers and back again (whereas `Strings` are a little harder to manipulate like that). For example, check out the `char` to `int` mapping on [this](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~pattis/15-1XX/common/handouts/ascii.html) page and see if anything jumps out at you...

Answer (score 1):

In Linux we have `tr` command which would replace characters

```
nsaravanas@ubuntu:~$ echo "abcdABCD1234" | tr "a-zA-Z0-9" "A-Za-zA-J"
ABCDabcdBCDE
nsaravanas@ubuntu:~$
```

In `Java` we can implement similar to `tr` to replace `char`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str = "abcdefghABCDEFGHI1234%*@)@*#&";
    String from = "a-zA-Z0-9";
    String to = "A-Za-zA-J";
    final char remaining = '#';
    String replaced = tr(from, to, remaining, str);
    System.out.println(replaced);
}

private static String tr(String from, String to, char def, String str) {
    Map<Character, Character> trMap = buildTRMap(from, to);
    return str.chars().mapToObj(ch -> trMap.getOrDefault((char) ch, def) + "").collect(Collectors.joining());
}

private static Map<Character, Character> buildTRMap(String from, String to) {
    Map<Character, Character> trMap = new HashMap<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < from.length(); i++) {
        if (i + 2 < from.length() && from.charAt(i + 1) == '-') {
            char fromStart = from.charAt(i);
            char fromEnd = from.charAt(i + 2);
            char toStart = to.charAt(i);
            char toEnd = to.charAt(i + 2);
            List<Character> fromL = IntStream.rangeClosed(fromStart, fromEnd).mapToObj(c -> (char) c).collect(Collectors.toList());
            List<Character> toL = IntStream.rangeClosed(toStart, toEnd).mapToObj(c -> (char) c).collect(Collectors.toList());
            IntStream.range(0, fromL.size()).forEach(in -> trMap.put(fromL.get(in), toL.get(in)));
            i += 2;
        } else {
            trMap.put(from.charAt(i), to.charAt(i));
        }
    }
    return trMap;
}
```

output

```
ABCDEFGHabcdefghiBCDE########
```

Comment: @Shreyas, A-J to 0-9 is not given in question

Answer (score 0):

This could be the simple solution can think of right now:

```
    for(int i=0;i<str.length();i++){//First it checks for numbers 0-9 and replaces them with characters between A to J, else if alphabets found, converts it to uppercase and lowercase, else convert that character to #

        if(str.charAt(i)=='0'){
            str.setCharAt(i, 'A');
        }else if(str.charAt(i)=='1'){
            str.setCharAt(i, 'B');
        }else if(str.charAt(i)=='2'){
            str.setCharAt(i, 'C');
        }else if(str.charAt(i)=='3'){
            str.setCharAt(i, 'D');
        }else if(str.charAt(i)=='4'){
            str.setCharAt(i, 'E');
        }else if(str.charAt(i)=='5'){
            str.setCharAt(i, 'F');
        }else if(str.charAt(i)=='6'){
            str.setCharAt(i, 'G');
        }else if(str.charAt(i)=='7'){
            str.setCharAt(i, 'H');
        }else if(str.charAt(i)=='8'){
            str.setCharAt(i, 'I');
        }else if(str.charAt(i)=='9'){
            str.setCharAt(i, 'J');
        }else if(Character.isLowerCase(str.charAt(i))){
            str.setCharAt(i, Character.toUpperCase(str.charAt(i)));
        }else if(Character.isUpperCase(str.charAt(i))){
            str.setCharAt(i, Character.toLowerCase(str.charAt(i)));
        }else{
            str.setCharAt(i, '#');
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at [`java.lang.Character`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html).

It has methods like `Character.isLowerCase('a')` and `Character.toUpperCase('a')`.

Comment: understand his question. if he has AbcD,, he wants to do aBCd... just by doing upper or lower it will convert all the character

Comment: Understand the answer. The methods in `Character` operate on single characters, not on the whole string.