# java - check String ArrayList for multiple specific integers/letters

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, arraylist

I am developing a puzzle program where a user inputs two String arrays (xs, ys), the length of the array could vary. Each element from each array is equivalent to each other. I have to search through both arrays and find similar values to solve it.

What I have done is create an ArrayList that contains the equivalent elements together. However, I have to filter the ArrayList to find specific values.

For example, if the user inputs 
         xs = [x, y, 1, x]
         ys = [3, 4, 1, 3]
This means that x = 3, y = 4, 1 = 1, x = 3

What I have to do now is filter the ArrayList (match) containing similar values, to make sure that it only contains one type of integer.
For example, if the user entered:
         xs = [x, y, 1, x]
         ys = [3, 4, 1, 5]
Then this would be invalid as x cannot be 3 and 5 at the same time.

I began writing the code by using IF statements, however, considering the possible values the user could enter, I realised that this is not efficient. I also realised that my solve boolean could be overriden too. I have copied my code below:

```
ArrayList<String> match = new ArrayList<String>();
for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    match.add(xs[i]); //filtering equivalent elements
    match.add(ys[i]);

    for (j = 0; j < size; j++) {
        if ((xs[i] == xs[j]) || ys[i] == ys[j] || xs[i] == ys[j] || ys[i] == xs[j]) {
            match.add(xs[j]); // adding any other values which are same
            match.add(ys[j]);
        }

        for (t = 0; t < match.size(); t++) {
            boolean hasDigit = (match.get(t)).matches(".*\\d.*");
            int digit = (-1); // initialising digit

            if (hasDigit && digit == (-1)) {
                digit = match.get(t); // all integers must be equal to this value to be considered valid
                solve = true;
            } else if (hasDigit && digit == match.get(t) && digit != (-1)) {
                solve = true;
            } else if (hasDigit && digit != match.get(t) && digit != (-1)) {
                solve = false;
            }
        }
```

The reason why I think this is wrong is because supposed I have 3 integer values for x (2, 5, 2). This would return as solve = true since digit = 2, and when 5 != 2, it will be false, but when it does 2 != 2, it will change to true. However, it is still invalid.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why are you putting parentheses around `-1`?

Comment: I'm used to it, helps things look clearer.

Comment: check my SO answer on a similar post http://stackoverflow.com/a/40099027/3344829

Answer (score 2):

I would approach this differently and use a `Map<String,String>` to store the equivalences. To process an (`xs[i]`, `ys[i]`) pair, the logic would be to look in the map for an existing value already bound to `xs[i]`. If none was found, add an entry binding `xs[i]` to `ys[i]`. If one was found, test that the bound value in the map is equal to `ys[i]`; if that fails, then set a "valid input" flag to `false`. (Initialize the flag to `true` before processing the arrays. During processing, the only possible change to the flag is to set it to `false`.)

Comment: Still, you are here making an assumption that [x,y,x] won't be valid entries even tho, he specified that  user can and will inputs the same vars at the first array.
Am I missing something here?

Comment: @AhmadAlsanie - If `xs` is `[x, y, x]` then it will be valid if `ys` has the same value at each position of `x` in `xs`. That's what OP described and that's what my approach will do.

Comment: Just to make it clear, ys can hold variables too.. So something like xs=[x, y, 1, x]  ys = [u, 2, 1, 3] would still be valid since x=u=3, y=2 and 1=1.

Comment: so it doesn't really matter if the first and the second arrays are holding vars as long as the first arr[1] = x and the second arr2[1]=x, yes that will work.
Thanks for the clarification.
+1

Comment: My approach will need a little modification to handle two variables at the same position in `xs` and `ys`. You'll need to distinguish bound values from aliases. That can be done by having a second map, this time a `Map<String, Set<String>>` that contains aliases for each variable. When you run across `x` and `u` at the same position, add an alias `u` for `x` and also an alias `x` for `u`. There'll have to be a little more logic thrown in to deal with this. (If any alias gets a bound value, they all do.)

Comment: No problem, all that matters it that the element at the same position is equivalent to each other... I will give mapping a go, I'm new to java and have never done it before.

Comment: @assassinweed2 - Okay. Good luck.

Comment: Hi sorry to bother you again, about having a second map I'm a little confused as to how that works. Will I have to create TWO maps? And if so, what will each of them contain? I just need some help breaking it down please.

Answer (score 0):

In your question you used the word "filter" twice. It seems logical that instead of the third loop and if-statements you need to put the list into a stream and use the filter() method with lambda expressions. This way, you will get rid of the explicit iteration and flags, which will make the code much cleaner:

```
match.stream()
     .filter(e -> ...)
     ...;
```